# Outerjoin is not merging as expected, are my specifications wrong?

Tags: matlab, join

I am trying to merge three tables using `outerjoin()` but I am not getting the result I want/expect. Below is the code I am using, the result I am getting, and the result I want. Using Matlab R2018a.

**Code**

```
%%% set up dummy data tables
Key1 = [1 1 1 2 2 3 3 3 3 3];
Key2 = [1 2 3 1 2 1 2 3 4 5];
Val1 = [0 NaN NaN 0 NaN 0.09 NaN NaN NaN NaN];
Val2 = [NaN 0.55 0.55 0.04 0.04 0.58 0.634 0.668 0.6950 0.7560];
mytable = array2table([Key1', Key2', Val1', Val2']);
mytable.Properties.VariableNames = {'Key1', 'Key2', 'Val1', 'Val2'};

temp1 = array2table([1 4 0; 2 3 0; 3 6 0.09]);
temp1.Properties.VariableNames = {'Key1', 'Key2', 'Val1'};

temp2 = array2table([1 4 0.55; 2 3 0.04; 3 6 0.07560]);
temp2.Properties.VariableNames = {'Key1', 'Key2', 'Val2'};

%%% try to join mytable, temp1, and temp2 together
Tout = outerjoin(mytable, temp1, 'MergeKeys', true);
Tout = outerjoin(Tout, temp2, 'MergeKeys', true);
```

**Result from code**
I want the highlight rows to be combined, such that the Key1-Key2 pair is not duplicated in the output table. I tried various combinations of `...'MergeKeys', true, 'LeftVariables', {'Key1', 'Key2', 'Val1', 'Val2'}, 'RightVariables', {'Key1', 'Key2', 'Val2'}` etc. but I couldn't get it to work.

[image: Current Result]

**Desired result**

[image: Desired Result]

Comment: Please [use text, not images/links, for text--including tables & ERDs](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097). Use images only for what cannot be expressed as text or to augment text. Include a legend/key & explanation with an image.

Comment: What does "clean that out" mean? Which of the multiple rows for left hand columns goes in the output? Part of a [mre]--is clear specification & explanation. PS As is & especially when you commit to which row you want this will be a faq. Google many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular strings/names & site:stackoverflow.com & tags; read many answers. PS Learn what LEFT JOIN ON returns: INNER JOIN ON rows UNION ALL unmatched left table rows extended by NULLs. Always know what INNER JOIN ON you want as part of an OUTER JOIN ON

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by reversing the order:

```
Tout = outerjoin(temp1, temp2, 'MergeKeys',true);
Tout = outerjoin(mytable, Tout, 'MergeKeys',true);
```